# Is it Possible to have a on click event inside a html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the small code snippet where the HTML tags are passed to a certain div having class name `message-container` Which is working fine.

```
chatHTML += '<div class="message-block">'+
'<div class="user-icon"></div>'+
'<div class="message">'+ doc.data().message +'</div>'+
'<i class="fas fa-reply onclick=expand(doc.data().message)"></i>'+
'</div>';

$(".message-container").html(chatHTML);
```

Can I able to add a onclick event the same so that i can pass a variable into it ?

I tried it with the above method by wrting onclick event and calling the function in same page as

```
 function expand(message)
{
console.log(message)
}
```

But it is giving error as `expand function is not defined`

Is there any other way to call a onClick Event Inside a HTML tag?

Comment: yes, but you need to use your `"` wisely ... I'd recommend using ` to enclose the whole string, then you have both ' and " to use as required

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you give the `createElement` approach a try.

You can simply

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.addEventListener('click', function () { alert('hi'); });
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

This was you will more fine tuned control on your javascript references.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="fas fa-reply onclick=expand(doc.data().message)"></i>
```

You have accidentally put onclick="()" inside of your classes. Let's fix that up, as well as adding "":

```
<i class="fas fa-reply" onclick="expand(doc.data().message)"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same as your code, but with a simple reproducible example:

```js
const someMessage = 'hello world';

document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="message-block">'+
'<div class="user-icon"></div>'+
'<div class="message">'+ someMessage +'</div>'+
'<i class="icon" onclick="expand(someMessage)"></i>'+
'</div>';

 function expand(message)
{
  console.log(message)
}
```

```css
.icon {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: red;
}
```

Seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The function **expand** is not defined or it does not exists, possibly because it is not in the same scope as the function that is calling it, which is created dynamically.

Instead of using the onclick attribute, use the .on function or the .click function instead.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let chatHTML = '';

    function expand(message) {
      console.log(message);
    }

    chatHTML += '<a class="message-block">' +
      '<div class="user-icon"></div>' +
      '<div class="message">Message</div>' +
      '<i class="fas fa-reply"></i>' +
      '</a>';

    $(".message-container").html(chatHTML);
    
    $(".message-block").on("click", function() {
      expand("message");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

It may be more applicable/appropriate to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). It allows you to assign a handler for elements not yet created.

Furthermore, try using a more modern approach to append html, like [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Here's an example, based on the code of your question

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

// add 2 blocks
document.querySelector("#chatHtml")
  .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <div class="message-block">Block 1
      <div class="user-icon"></div>
      <div class="message"></div>
      <b class="fas fa-reply">ⓘ</b>
    </div>
  `);
  
document.querySelector("#chatHtml")
  .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <div class="message-block">Block 2
      <div class="user-icon"></div>
      <div class="message"></div>
      <b class="fas fa-reply">ⓘ</b>
    </div>
  `);

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  
  if (origin.classList.contains("fa-reply")) {
  //                    ∟ only if clicked on b.fa-reply
  const messageBlock = origin.closest(".message-block");
  //                          ∟ retrieve the parent div.message-block
  messageBlock.querySelector(".message").textContent = 
  //                         ∟ fill div.message with some text
        `It's ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} and you clicked!`;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}
.fa-reply {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatHtml"></div>
```